# Stop all slack interactive buttons from disappearing after clicking one

Tags: slack, slack-api

We have an interactive message with multiple buttons. When one is clicked, all of them disappear. We want the unclicked buttons to remain.

We've searched through reams of documentation to no avail.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you tell something more about what is the functionality of that button or maybe the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option that allows you to directly choose that the other buttons shall remain.

Instead here are two ways how to achieve your requirement:

1. Respond with overwriting the original message (default behavior) with a new message containing only the remaining buttons
2. Respond without overwriting the original message by setting `replace_original` to `false` and update the
   original message with your app to remove the clicked button, using the API method [`chat.update`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update)

See [this part](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#responding) of the official documentation for details.